# How can i get the real current height of a stackpanel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, panel, stackpanel

Hallo,

i want to make a custom stackpanel in WPF, which shall automatically resizes his childs to a certain size depending on the panels height. But the panels height is dynamic because it stretches to his parent. When i want to get the height (i tried all possibilities, see code), it is always 0 or not defined, although in the build solution it is definitely not 0.
Here's the code:

XAML:

`<my:AutoSizeButtonStackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>`

Code-Behind:

```
public class AutoSizeButtonStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public void AddChild(Button newButton)
    {
        double getPanelHeight;
        getPanelHeight = this.ActualHeight; //is 0
        getPanelHeight = this.ViewportHeight; //is 0
        getPanelHeight = this.Height; //is n. def.
        getPanelHeight = this.DesiredSize.Height; //is 0
        getPanelHeight = this.RenderSize.Height; //is 0

        newButton.Height = getPanelHeight / 2;

        this.Children.Add(newButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might have to do with **when** you actually query `this.ActualHeight`. At the time `AddChild()` is called the height really might still be 0 because [the measure pass and the arrange pass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) might not have been through yet. Everything that affects the measure and layout of your children should be done in [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) and [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx)

You should have a look at how to write custom Panels. There are tons of ressources on this topic out there. I personally think that [this](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/custom-layout-in-wpf/) is a good and simple enough tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, good tutorial (even simple enough for me :-P )
Had to put the resize logic in ArrangeOverride, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

ActualHeight is the correct property, but at the point where you're reading it, the height is not calculated yet.

Follow this link to find out the recommended way of building a custom layout panel: http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html

Comment: I already knew this tutorial, but it's not profound enough and doesn't clear my problem.